# Does GeoServer's WorldImage plugin use UTM or WGS84 (EPSG:4326)?

Tags: geoserver

I have some PNG images that I want to put on an OpenLayers map using GeoServer as a WMS, and it seems as though the easiest way to do that would be to create an accompanying `.pnw` file (ESRI world file) for each `.png` and load them using GeoServer's WorldImage plugin.

I also have the longitude, latitude coordinates of nine points on each rectangular image: {top, middle, bottom} x {left, middle, right}, and I can use five of them to convert pixel x,y into longitude, latitude x',y':

[image: x' = \left(\frac{mr_{lng} - ml_{lng}}{width}\right) x + \left(\frac{tm_{lng} - bm_{lng}}{height}\right) y + \left(mm_{lng} + \frac{mr_{lng} - ml_{lng}}{2} + \frac{tm_{lng} - bm_{lng}}{2}\right)]
[image: y' = \left(\frac{mr_{lat} - ml_{lat}}{width}\right) x + \left(\frac{tm_{lat} - bm_{lat}}{height}\right) y + \left(mm_{lat} + \frac{mr_{lat} - ml_{lat}}{2} + \frac{tm_{lat} - bm_{lat}}{2}\right)]

where (mm_lng, mm_lat) is the position of the middle-middle point, (mr_lng, mr_lat) is middle-right, (tm_lng, tm_lat) is top-middle, etc. for the middles of the four sides.  This is a linear approximation to the full coordinate transformation, minimizing error at the center of the image.

The World Image format describes an affine transformation in the same way: the six parenthesized terms above can be interpreted as the six lines of the `.pnw` file (in A, B, C, D, E, F order) if the map units are longitude, latitude coordinates (that is, WGS84 a.k.a. EPSG:4326).  The [World file Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) says "World files describing a map on the Universal Transverse Mercator coordinate system (UTM) use these conventions..." and goes on to describe the UTM application, though it also says, "World files do not specify a coordinate system; this information is generally stored somewhere else."

If the result of the `.pnw` conversion is interpreted as UTM, then I would need to do additional work to transform from WGS84 into UTM, and GeoServer would also need more information to specify which of the 60 UTM zones that the `.pnw` converts into.  I don't see how to provide that information to GeoServer.  Am I right in assuming that GeoServer interprets the `.pnw`-converted coordinates as WGS84?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geoserver does not get to makeup a projection. The WorldImage uses the projection it is told to use.

The key is the statement

> World files do not specify a coordinate system; this information is generally stored somewhere else.

In your case, that 'somewhere else' is in a .prj file.  The units in your world file have to match the coordinate system defined in your prj file.

An easy way to get that data is to go to http://epsg.io/ and lookup the projection information.  It is also available in the 'SRS List' in the demos section of geoserver.

Paste the OGC WKT for your projection in the .prj file.  If your points are all lat's & lon's, EPSG:4326 may be the correct projection:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's been so long since I was working on this that I don't fully understand my own question, let alone the answer.  I hope it's useful for somebody.  I'm going to mark this as the correct answer because it looks plausible, but I can't say I've tested it.